# Total Sum of amount after Buying and selling Product in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have a simple product table with different product. I want calculable current product amount from given table.

```
SL  Name    Buy Sell
1   Apple   10  0
2   Apple   0   9
3   Apple   15  0
4   Apple   0   10
5   Apple   5   0
6   Orance  15  0
7   Orance  0   20
8   Orance  30  0
9   Orance  0   10
10  Orance  15  0
```

What I want to calculate is how may fruits are in my basket now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `sum` as follows:

```
select name, sum(buy) - sum(sell) as in_my_basket
from your_table 
group by name;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to aggregate the data and subtract the sells from the buys:

```
select fruit, sum(buy) - sum(sell) as net
from t
group by fruit;
```